# Getting the error of VersionedTransaction too large

Tags: versionedtransactions

I am getting the error while sending the version transaction
encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction too large: 1776 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1644/1232)
Any clue about this?

Comment: Versioned transactions are still limited to 1232 bytes, that limit is unchanged. You might be able to use an address lookup table to make your transaction smaller (if you're using a v0 transaction), but you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Is there any demo of using addressLookUpTable ? @CallumM

Comment: There are some code samples here: https://beta.docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables#versioned-transactions